# what should I do if div overlaps with position absolute and relative on one of them

Tags: html, css

I created a div in which I arranged the pictures and also applied pos:absolute and relative to them. what's the problem: I created a new div, which is located under the div with pictures. what to do?

```css
.posts {
  display: block;
  top: 128px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.purpule {
  color: #592ea9;
}
```

```html
<div class="posts">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left__post">
      Featured Post
      <div class="post">
        <img src="img/post_img.png" alt=":(" />
        <div class="left__post">
          <div class="left__post1">
            By <span class="purpule">John Doe</span> l May 23, 2022
          </div>
          <div class="left__post2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing <br /> elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.
          </div>
          <div class="left__post3">
            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore <br /> eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident.
          </div>
          <div class="main__txt5">Read More ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"What to do?"*; I'd recommend reading [tour] and [ask] to include a [mre] so we can help you.

Comment: So what do you want to achieve?